# Using react-css-modules with sass not working

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack, react-css-modules

I am trying to get [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules)'s to work whilst using sass but just can't get it working. I am following the documentation and it should just work at this point.

**Scss include in jsx**

```
import home from "../../scss/pages/_home.scss"

export default React.createClass({

    render() {
        return <app-content styleName={home.home}>
              }
         />
        </app-content>;
    }
})
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
        {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: [
            'style?sourceMap',
            'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            'resolve-url',
            'sass?sourceMap']},
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap&modules" },
```

Of course there are no js errors and the following gets output to my elements once compiled:

```
<app-content stylename="src-client-scss-pages-____home__home___JTSxY"></app-content>
```

But there just aren't any styles at all.

Answer (score 0):

Urgh...

Ok, I thought about deleting the question but thought maybe if it could save somebody wasting 2 hours for such a stupidly simple thing why not post the answer:

```
    return <app-content class={home.home}>
```

The change being from `styleName` on the element with the style to the intuitive and obvious answer: `class`.

Good luck people!